# loading jQuery with dojoConfig $ still not defined in time

Tags: jquery, dojo

The dojoConfig is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    dojoConfig = {
        async: true,
        parseOnLoad: false,
        packages: [
                  { name: 'jquery', location: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1', main: 'jquery.min' },
                  { name: 'jqueryui', location: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1', main: 'jquery-ui.min' }
        ]
    };                 
</script>
```

I am loading from the googles:

The following will demo the issue:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   define.amd.jQuery = true;
   require(["jquery", "dojo/domReady!"], function (jquery) { 
       $(document).ready(function () { 
          console.log("First ready!"); //works
       }); 
   });
   $(document).ready(function(){console.log("ready!");});//throws error
</script>
```

It seems to be a timing issue as the Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined is written to the console before "First ready!" is written out. Would like to use either of the ready functions. Any ideas on how to work it out? If not then we can wrap all root level $ function in dojo/ready functions, kinda icky though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get $ as `undefined` because jquery is loaded correctly and cdn version asfaik cannot be use use directly in your `dojoConfig`.

To solve the issue, the simple way would be to try to include jquery from cdn adding script tags in your html `<header>` as:

```
<header>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</header>
```

Alternatively you could try to load jquery as a non-amd module module as described in dojo documentation:

https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules_advanced/

Instead if you do not use cdn you could try the following:

```
    <!-- any external libraries configuration included in header -->
    <!-- dojo config -->
    <script>
            var dojoConfig = {
                baseUrl: "./",
                async: true,
                isDebug: true,
                parseOnLoad: false,
                packages: [
                    {name: "dojo", location: "libs/dojo"},
                    {name: "dijit", location: "libs/dijit"},
                    {name: "dojox", location: "libs/dojox"},
                    {name: "jquery", location: "libs/jquery", main: "jquery-3.1.1"},
                    {name: "jqueryui", location: "libs/jquery", main: "jquery-ui-1.12.1"},
                ]

            };
    </script>
```

Comment: I had the jquery in the header but it was not the first script library being loaded. I moved them to the top and they loaded just fine. I no longer have them referenced in the packages of the dojoConfig either.